# WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWorkByTag() not stopping the periodic job

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

for periodic task I am using work manager as:

```
PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder wifiWorkBuilder =
                            new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(FileUpload.class, 15,
                                    TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                                    .setConstraints(new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.METERED).build());
                    PeriodicWorkRequest wifiWork = wifiWorkBuilder.build();
                    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("wifiJob", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, wifiWork);
```

I have one activity in that activity one check box is there if user unselect checkbox then I want to stop this job. So I am stopping job like:

```
WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWorkByTag("wifiJob");
```

But after stopping job also my task is executing. Previously I thought might be next job will be executed and after that it will stop but in last 1 hour it executed 4 times and still job is running in background. What is other way or correct way to stop job.

as per Docs:

> Cancels all unfinished work with the given tag. Note that cancellation is a best-effort policy and work that is already executing may continue to run.

What is the meaning of this -  cancellation is a best-effort policy and work that is already executing may continue to run. So what is the correct way to stop this

I am using version `implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha08"`
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 39, accepted):

While creating PeriodicWorkRequest i had added addTag() and to cancel task used same tag name, using this it cancel pending work. So my code is like:

```
PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder wifiWorkBuilder =
                            new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(FileUpload.class, 15,
                                    TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                                    .addTag("WIFIJOB1")
                                    .setConstraints(new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.METERED).build());
                    wifiWork = wifiWorkBuilder.build();
                    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("wifiJob", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, wifiWork);
```

To stop job I am using:

```
WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWorkByTag("WIFIJOB1");
```

Comment: For future readers, [the method](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#cancelUniqueWork(java.lang.String)) `cancelUniqueWork(String workName)` exists!  :)

Comment: @varun What is workerName for use in cancelUniqueWork()?

Comment: @roghayeh hosseini Oh, use the name you had given when you created it with ```beginUniqueWork(String uniqueWorkName, ...)``` method.

Comment: getInstance() is deprecated. Now need to use getInstance(context)

Comment: cancelAllWork() is also existed. This helped me in most cases. This will stop all remaining workers.

Answer (score 12):

I believe the problem you are having here is answered in this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924702/how-to-make-sure-that-workmanager-cancels-my-worker).

In summary, if you have a pending worker which hasn't started yet, the worker will be cancelled and will not run. However **if the worker is already running**, cancelling work does not terminate the worker in a hard fashion - it simply sets the state flag of the worker to `CANCELLED`, [as explained in the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/cancel-stop-work). It is up to you to handle the cancellation inside your `doWork` and terminate the worker.

One way to do this is to put a few checks in your `doWork` method to check if the worker has been cancelled, by calling `isStopped()`. If `isStopped` is true, return from the method with a `Result` instead of continuing with the rest of the work.

Answer (score 2):

I've been checking the official Android docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager

There are two types of work supported by WorkManager: **OneTimeWorkRequest** and **PeriodicWorkRequest**.

You can enqueue requests using WorkManager as follows:

```
 WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
 workManager.enqueue(new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(FooWorker.class).build());
```

A WorkRequest has an associated id that can be used for lookups and observation as follows:

```
WorkRequest request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(FooWorker.class).build();
 workManager.enqueue(request);
 LiveData<WorkStatus> status = workManager.getStatusById(request.getId());
 status.observe(...);
```

You can also use the id for cancellation:

```
WorkRequest request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(FooWorker.class).build();
 workManager.enqueue(request);
 workManager.cancelWorkById(request.getId());
```

And here you can see a different ways to cancel a enqueued work:

[image]

Maybe you also can try to cancel a enqueued or blocked job using the State of the job:

```
WorkStatus workStatus = WorkManager.getInstance().getStatusById(wifiWork.getId()).getValue();
        if(workStatus.getState() == State.ENQUEUED || workStatus.getState() == State.BLOCKED){
            WorkManager.getInstance().cancelWorkById(wifiWork.getId());

        }
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I want to upload files after every 15 min therefore I had used PeriodicWorkRequest. But using checkbox user can cancel uploading file at any time when he wants. So to cancel this I am using  cancelAllWorkByTag () and pasing same tag which was used at time of creation of task. But its not getting cancelled the pending task

Comment: I edited the code with a new suggestion using WorkStatus

Comment: Hi Tested with your new code but still some times it not stop the job

Comment: Hi. I will test in this weekend and if i find something that could fix it i will tell you