# WorkManager not being replaced using ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Calling ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE just starts another workManager it doesn't replace the other one, multiple workManagers are running when triggered not replaced

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build()

    val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<SongsWorker>(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .addTag(TAG)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance(mContext).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
        TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest)
```

The log suggests the work manager is at least asking to be cancelled, but the execution continues

```
I/WM-WorkerWrapper: Work [ id=6ed5487e-5d7b-4db5-a4c5-c22c562567e5, tags={ 
workerManagers.songs.SongsWorkerManager$SongsWorker } ] was cancelled
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.cancellationExceptionWithCause(AbstractFuture.java:1184)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:514)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:475)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:300)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I have attached a listener to the work manager and the log is

```
2021-04-30 20:40:54.318 17868-17868 Fragment: ID = 9f8b3165-fc75-4f9a-ba39-41c2dc6a17b3
2021-04-30 20:40:54.408 17868-17868 Fragment: ID = 9f8b3165-fc75-4f9a-ba39-41c2dc6a17b3
2021-04-30 20:40:54.427 17868-17868 Fragment: ID = 9f8b3165-fc75-4f9a-ba39-41c2dc6a17b3
```

The listener is:

```
val instance = WorkManager.getInstance(requireContext())
  instance.getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData(SongsWorkerManager.TAG)
        .observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { workInfo ->
            workInfo.forEach {
                Log.d(TAG, "ID = ${it.id}")
            }
        }
```

After triggering the work manager 3 times, 3 identical work managers are running rather then being replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is having trouble stopping a work manager with ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, call

```
if (isStopped) return Result.success()
```

inside doWork() and you will get the behaviour you expect.

Thanks to

[WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWorkByTag() not stopping the periodic job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218304/workmanager-getinstance-cancelallworkbytag-not-stopping-the-periodic-job)

""One way to do this is to put a few checks in your doWork method to check if the worker has been cancelled, by calling isStopped(). If isStopped is true, return from the method with a Result instead of continuing with the rest of the work.""

and

[How to make sure that WorkManager cancels my Worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924702/how-to-make-sure-that-workmanager-cancels-my-worker)

Answer (score 1):

The above logs are not justifying that the old workers are not canceled. You can add the following observer to check the current status of all the workers through `WorkInfo`

```
WorkManager.getInstance(context).getWorkInfosByTagLiveData(TAG)
            .observe(lifecycleOwner, { workInfo ->
                workInfo.forEach { 
                    println("Worker Info -> $it")
                }
            })
```