# Problem with Androids "OneTimeWorker", it executes when app starts

Tags: java, android, worker

#### Short description:

I am currently working in Android Studio with `OneTimeWorkRequest()`. What I want to achieve is to create a background-worker that runs and repeats **"almost"** on a specific time, like every hour (09:00, 10:00, etc). It has not to be exactly but should not vary too much after a long time running.

I already know that the worker only runs every 15 minutes at minimum due to Android restrictions (like battery saving mechanism and so on). I do not need the worker to run exactly at the given time but at least almost around a target time! That is why I used `OneTimeWorkRequest()` instead of `PeriodicWorkRequest()` because I needed the possibility of variation in setting the interval for the worker since the documentation mentions that the `PeriodicWorkRequest()` will add up a time delay from one execution to another.

#### What I did:

I have created a custom Worker-Class and used `OneTimeWorkRequest()` in my `MainActivity` to create the BackgroundWorker. I have set the `setInitialDelay()` of the worker to 20 minutes for testing purpose. Every time the worker did `doWork()`, it creates another `OneTimeWorkRequest()` at the end of execution so a chain of worker gets created in at a given time. The worker gets queued with the `enqueueUniqueWork()` method from the `WorkerManager.getInstance(context)` and the interval is calculated.

#### The Problem:

Every time I close the app's process and reopen the app, the worker executes directly. Also when I list all worker created by the specified tag, it lists many workers. It seems to me that my logic created too many worker without closing the old ones, or it creates multiple ones? Yet I thought the `enqueueUniqueWork()` would replace or create only unique/single worker with the given tag. In addition the `WorkManager.getInstance(this).cancelAllWorkByTag(TAG)` function does not close the (later in this post) listed worker!

Right now it is not important for me how to create worker execution at a given time, but how to create consistent worker-chain with `OneTimeWorkRequest()` that do not create a "worker-overload", if possible. Yet I am open for alternative solutions.

So again:

- Why does the worker execute after closing the process and opening the App?
- Why are there so many workers listed?
- Does my logic create one single worker chain or multiple ones?
- Is my logic even consistent/usable like this?
- Why are the worker not closing using `.cancelAllWorkByTag(TAG)`?

#### Code:

MainActivity.java:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    ...
    
        // For testing purpose used...
    ListScheduledWorker(TAG);
    WorkManager.getInstance(this).cancelAllWorkByTag(TAG);
    ListScheduledWorker(TAG);
        // ...until here.

    CreateOneTimeWorker();
    
    ...
}

private void CreateOneTimeWorker(){
    long timeValue = 20;
    TimeUnit timeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES;
    String workerTag = MhdExpirationPushNotification.class.getSimpleName();
    OneTimeWorkRequest worker = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(CustomPeriodicallyWorker.class)
            .setInitialDelay(timeValue, timeUnit)
            .addTag(workerTag)
            .setConstraints(Constraints.NONE)
            .build();
    WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniqueWork(workerTag, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, worker);
}
```

CustomPeriodicallyWorker.java:

```java
public Result doWork(){
    Log.v(TAG, "Work is in progress");
    try {
        CustomDateFormatter currentDateTime = new CustomDateFormatter();
        CustomDateFormatter targetDateTime = new CustomDateFormatter();
        targetDateTime.AddMinutes(20);
        long timeDifference = targetDateTime.GetDateTime().getTime() - currentDateTime.GetDateTime().getTime();

        OneTimeWorkRequest worker = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(CustomPeriodicallyWorker.class)
                .setInitialDelay(timeDifference, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .addTag(TAG)
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniqueWork(TAG, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, worker);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.v(TAG, "Work finished");;

    return Result.success();
}
```

The function in `MainActivity.java` that lists all scheduled worker:

```java
private boolean ListScheduledWorker(String tag) {
    WorkManager instance = WorkManager.getInstance(this);
    ListenableFuture<List<WorkInfo>> statuses = instance.getWorkInfosByTag(tag);
    try {
        boolean running = false;
        List<WorkInfo> workInfoList = statuses.get();
        for (WorkInfo workInfo : workInfoList) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Scheduled Worker running with ID: " + workInfo.getId());
            WorkInfo.State state = workInfo.getState();
            running = state == WorkInfo.State.RUNNING | state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED;
        }
        return running;
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `ListScheduledWorker(String tag)` prints me this out:

```
I/TAG: Scheduled Worker running with ID: 27bb31ed-5984-434f-a6ca-08b50462b3df
    Scheduled Worker running with ID: 2d6abbb1-3a55-4652-83ca-60617631e0ab
    Scheduled Worker running with ID: 3e89851d-7e0b-410d-86b8-e664a4d710f0
    Scheduled Worker running with ID: 430e77b2-5fb8-4596-acd5-51e35a6a538b
    Scheduled Worker running with ID: 73b57443-8195-4c55-a24d-bd643b88e13c
    Scheduled Worker running with ID: 74c8a44b-2a9a-4448-b3d5-e2c085be3d06
    Scheduled Worker running with ID: 75deabd3-08e8-403a-b9d7-6c23f114a908
    Scheduled Worker running with ID: 89ec6239-e215-4ea1-a7bc-fcaa8b63065c
    Scheduled Worker running with ID: 9363038e-be74-4a83-9d1f-eeeda35ebbfa
    Scheduled Worker running with ID: 9a09806f-f0cf-43c1-a4f6-1f10448904f4
    Scheduled Worker running with ID: c6686c56-fd8a-4866-8eb1-5124654b6cb7
    Scheduled Worker running with ID: d3343328-db8f-4c8d-8055-a1acfc9d1c5c
    Scheduled Worker running with ID: dea9272f-6770-45f0-ba66-2c845e156d7b
    Scheduled Worker running with ID: eb4c111c-97c5-46c3-ba5c-ceefe652398c
    Scheduled Worker running with ID: fc71f8dc-1785-43cd-9a44-1fe4e913ca6e
    Scheduled Worker running with ID: fca1bcea-97d9-4066-8b5a-8b5496ffed1e
```

..and the list grows every time when I rebuild/restart the app in Android Studio or on my physical device.

Comment: Did you manage to find out what was the problem?

Comment: @BratislavDamnjanovic Unfortunately not. I had to pause the project for a while but will work on it in the future again. Hope I'll solve it until then

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer some of these to my best knowledge.

> Why does the worker execute after closing the process and opening the
> App?

Not sure, but you can cancel all unique work with that tag on app startup, which will stop it from automatically executing.

> Why are there so many workers listed?

`WorkManager` keeps `WorkInfo`s in it's internal database and cleans it automatically when it thinks its best time to do so.
You can use `workmanager.pruneWork()` to do this cleaning yourself, but use it with caution as explained in the documentation.

> Does my logic create one single worker chain or multiple ones?

It creates single chain since you are using `uniqeWork` and `ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE`.

> Is my logic even consistent/usable like this?

I do not see a reason why it should not be, you created your own implementation of periodic worker which can be executed with less than 15 minutes period.

> Why are the worker not closing using .cancelAllWorkByTag(TAG)?

If it is not cancelling it is most likely doe your code. Cancelation is on best effort, as explained in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/manage-work#cancelling), so you need to check for it.
I will quote separate [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56891687/6845311):

> In summary, if you have a pending worker which hasn't started yet, the
> worker will be cancelled and will not run. However if the worker is
> already running, cancelling work does not terminate the worker in a
> hard fashion - it simply sets the state flag of the worker to
> CANCELLED, as explained in the docs. It is up to you to handle the
> cancellation inside your doWork and terminate the worker.
>
> One way to do this is to put a few checks in your doWork method to
> check if the worker has been cancelled, by calling isStopped(). If
> isStopped is true, return from the method with a Result instead of
> continuing with the rest of the work.

Also double check that same tags are used. Since you are using `uniqueWork` you can also use `cancelUniqueWork`.